# Why Workspace.QueryConflicts does not work?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I want to check if there is code conflicts between branches across the entire TFS. It seems like [Workspace.QueryConflicts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.queryconflicts.aspx) doesn't work because it returns no conflicts while there are when I tried to merge code using tf.exe.

So, I do an experiment by using [Workspace.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.merge.aspx) to see if I can merge code between 2 branches or not and it says I cannot because there are code conflicts, see the code below for reference.

```
private static bool CheckMerge2(string branchFrom, string branchTo)
{
    if (branchFrom == branchTo ||
        !branchFrom.Contains("Common") ||
        !branchTo.Contains("Common"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can merge from '{0}' to '{1}'?", branchFrom, branchTo);

        using (var projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collection), windowsCredential))
        {
            // get the source code control service. 
            var sourceControl = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var workspace = sourceControl.GetWorkspace(@"E:\my_location\"); // Common\Master");

            try
            {
                GetStatus getStatus = workspace.Merge(branchFrom, branchTo, null, null, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.NoMerge);

                Console.WriteLine("Number of conflicts is {0}", getStatus.NumConflicts);

                if (getStatus.NumConflicts > 0)
                {
                    var conflicts = workspace.QueryConflicts(new string[] { branchTo }, true);

                    foreach (var conflict in conflicts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("This line will never hit");
                        Console.WriteLine(conflict.GetFullMessage());
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The result against my TFS is here:

[image]

As you can see, it says 1 conflict but there is no conflict messages print out. I am curious if I have done something wrong or it's a bug on .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and found that if you use `MergeOptions.NoMerge` as parameter to `workspace.Merge` then `workspace.QueryConflicts()` will return 0 conflict.

But if you change it to any other value like `MergeOptions.None` you will get the result in `workspace.QueryConflicts`.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal when you use "No merge options", your workspace doesn't contains changes or conflicts.

Use the "None" option instead and I would suggest you use the MergeOptionsEx class (instead of regular mergeOptions) -->regular mergeOptions doesn't autoresolve changes and you will get "conflict" status for each change even when there is no conflict.

Also in Powershell this didn't work:

```
$conflicts = $workspace.QueryConflicts([string[]] {$TFSTargetLocation}, $true);
```

but this did:

```
$conflicts = $workspace.QueryConflicts($TFSTargetLocation, $true);
```

I'm using TFS 2010 so maybe that's why